# init.d script failing to start

Tags: upstart, init.d

`sudo /etc/init.d/autovpn start` works
yet `sudo service autovpn start` will not

i have done `update-rc.d autovpn defaults`

the link is in /etc/rc.5

runlevel returns N 5